# Is it possible to persist stick-tables across server reloads in Haproxy

Tags: haproxy

I have read https://github.com/haproxy/haproxy/blob/master/examples/seamless_reload.txt on how to set up persisting the server state when you reload, but this does not save/load the contents on stick-tables. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible using peers which is setup with multi-master replication. From the [Peers section of the haproxy docs](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.7/configuration.html#3.5):

> It is possible to propagate entries of any data-types in stick-tables
>   between several haproxy instances over TCP connections in a
>   multi-master fashion. Each instance pushes its local updates and
>   insertions to remote peers. The pushed values overwrite remote ones
>   without aggregation. Interrupted exchanges are automatically detected
>   and recovered from the last known point. In addition, during a soft
>   restart, the old process connects to the new one using such a TCP
>   connection to push all its entries before the new process tries to
>   connect to other peers. That ensures very fast replication during a
>   reload, it typically takes a fraction of a second even for large
>   tables. Note that Server IDs are used to identify servers remotely, so
>   it is important that configurations look similar or at least that the
>   same IDs are forced on each server on all participants.

Comment: That's a good option, though I was looking for something like `server-state-file` that does not rely on peering. For now I managed to do it by updating the init scripts to save/restore it to a file using the stats socket.

Comment: @BalazsRau Could you share the commands you used? I can see how `show table` can be used to save a table, but how do you restore it? There is `set table`, but that seems to require a different format.

Comment: @EM0: I haven't looked at this for over a year, but this is what I found in my notes. Hope it helps.

Comment: cat <<EOF > /usr/sbin/haproxy-init/save.sh  
#!/bin/bash  
RESTORE_SERVER_ID=$(echo "show table sql-db" | socat - /var/lib/haprox/stats | perl -lne '/server_id=(\d+)/ && print $1')  
`echo "Haproxy save RESTORE_SERVER_ID=$RESTORE_SERVER_ID"`
`echo $RESTORE_SERVER_ID > /var/run/haproxy-sql-db.state`
`EOF`

Comment: cat <<EOF > /usr/sbin/haproxy-init/restore.sh
#!/bin/bash
SQL_STICK_TABLE_KEY=$(sleep 1; echo "show table sql-db" | socat - /var/lib/haproxy/stats | perl -lne '/key=(\S+)/ and print $1')
RESTORE_SERVER_ID=$(cat /var/run/haproxy-sql-db.state)
echo "set table sql-db key $SQL_STICK_TABLE_KEY data.server_id $RESTORE_SERVER_ID" | socat - /var/lib/haproxy/stats
echo "Haproxy restore SQL_STICK_TABLE_KEY=$SQL_STICK_TABLE_KEY RESTORE_SERVER_ID=$RESTORE_SERVER_ID"
EOF

Comment: Sorry for the formatting; could not figure out how to do it the right way.

Comment: Thanks! I haven't tried this yet, but this looks a bit like it would save/restore only one sticky table entry per script invocation. How did you save/restore them all?